# Preservar Actividad después de presionar el botón "Atrás"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

Estoy trabajando una aplicación con [android](/questions/tagged/android) la cual realiza una autenticación a través de una `actividad "A"` (**LoginActivity**), este instancia la `actividad "B"` (**LoginTask**) que hereda de **AsyncTask** para realizar dicho proceso, una vez realizada la autenticación se instancia a la `actividad "C"` (**PrincipalActivity**), siendo algo como esto A -> B -> C.

Ubicado en la `actividad "C"`, presiono el botón "Atras" y este me "saca" de la actividad principal y me ubica en la `actividad "A"`, decir, me regresa a la pantalla de *logueo*. Aquí mi código:

**LoginActivity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf");

        final EditText txtUser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
        txtUser.setTypeface(font);
        final EditText txtPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        txtPass.setTypeface(font);
        Button btnAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAccess);
        btnAccess.setTypeface(font);

        btnAccess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Login loginBean = new Login();
                String user = txtUser.getText().toString().trim();
                String pass = txtPass.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!user.equals("")) {
                    if(!pass.equals("")) {
                        loginBean.setUser(user.toUpperCase());
                        loginBean.setPass(pass);
                    } else {
                        txtPass.setError(getString(R.string.err_pass));
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    txtUser.setError(getString(R.string.err_user));
                    return;
                }

                LoginTask loginTask = new LoginTask(LoginActivity.this,loginBean);
                loginTask.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**LoginTask**

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Context context;
    private Resources resources;
    private Login loginParams;
    private String msgAccess;

    public LoginTask(Context context, Login loginParams) {
        this.context = context;
        this.resources = context.getResources();
        this.loginParams = loginParams;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.msg_access));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        //Autenticación
        return msgAccess;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        if (msgAccess != null) {
            if (msgAccess.equals("OK")) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(context, PrincipalActivity.class);
               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               context.startActivity(intent);
               ((Activity)context).finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, msgAccess, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.err_msg_null, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } 
}
```

Entonces, lo que habia pensado era realizar algun tipo de validación en el evento `onBackPressed()` de mi clase principal para que cuando presione el botón "Atras" no me regrese a "A", sino, me mantenga en la actividad principal "C":

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (LoginPersistence.getStatus() > 0 && !LoginPersistence.getToken().equals("")) {
 //Agregar aqui la validación
    }
}
```

Para ser mas explicito, lo que indico es que cuando estoy en mi actividad principal "C" y presiono el botón "Atrás", este me regresa a la actividad "A", es decir, para ingresar nuevamente usuario y *password*, cuando no debería hacerlo. Al presionar el botón "Atrás", debería "minimizar" mi aplicación y cuando vuelva a ingresar debería mantenerla en la actividad principal. Es lo que hago cuando presiono el botón "Home", me minimiza la aplicación y cuando vuelvo, me carga donde me quedé y esto lo logro con `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`.

Espero haberme explicado. Gracias.

Answer (score 8):

En base a tu pregunta, deseas regresar a la "actividad B",  `LoginTask` pero recuerda que esta en realidad no es una `Actividad` es un `AsyncTask`.

> - "A" (LoginActivity)
> - "B" (LoginTask)
> - "C" (PrincipalActivity)

`LoginTask` es un `Thread` que en realidad realiza un `Intent` para abrir la actividad `PrincipalActivity`.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, PrincipalActivity.class);
```

Si deseas regresar a "B" `LoginTask`, entonces esta clase debe extender de `Activity` y dentro de esta clase un instancia el `Asynctask` con la misma funcionalidad.

Comment: En realidad no deseo volver a la actividad "B", sino mas bien, preservar la actividad principal "C", luego de haber presionado el botón "atrás". Dado que cuando presiono el botón "atrás", me regresa a la actividad "A", la idea es mantenerlo en "C". Gracias.

Comment: Brando en la respuesta/propuesta que te anexo debajo puedes lograr que  no te regrese a ninguna actividad, pero no te dejara sobre la actividad "C" simplemente cerrara tu aplicacion si no hay nada detras de ella a donde regresar.

Answer (score 3):

LoginTask no es una actividad, es una tarea asíncrona, y esta puedes declararla dentro de LoginActivity.

Después de verificar la autenticación en **MainActivity** inicia **LoginActivity** así:

```
    if(!isAuthenticated){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Lo que hicimos aquí fue **finalizar la MainActivity después de lanzar LoginActivity**, entonces si la autenticación no fue correcta o no se realizó nada entonces cuando presiones atrás se saldrá de la aplicación sin volver a la actividad principal.

Después de haberte autenticado correctamente solo debes iniciar de nuevo la actividad principal **"MainActivity"** entonces la inicias de esta manera aplicando el mismo principio de arriba:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent)
LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

Con esto debería ser suficiente para regresar de **LoginActivity** a **MainActivity** después de iniciar sesión y cuando presiones atrás se terminará la aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

En tu AndroidManifest.xml debes incorporar `android:noHistory="true"`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

y esa actividad no será almacenada en el historial de actividades.

Comment: Gracias @cristhoper, voy a revisar lo que indicas.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, en lugar de `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` cuando inicias tu actividad:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Eso a mi me ha funcionado, cuando presiones "back" debe simplemente cerrar tu aplicación.

Espero te funcione.

Comment: No está respondiendo la pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que responde Elenasys es correcto. `LoginTask` es una `AsyncTask`, con lo cual no es una `Activity`. No puedes "volver a ella".
Si quieres entender algo más sobre el estado de tu *stack* de activities, puedes correr el siguiente comando de adb:

```
adb shell dumpsys activities
```

Ahí podrás ver cómo están tus actividades y comprender qué pasará cuando pulsas "back".